# How do you get ELMAH to throw its own exceptions?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

There used to be an article at ELMAHs docs site that contained this information, but it seems to have been removed. I think it's as simple as setting a configuration setting in the  section, but I haven't a clue what it is

Can anyone take a few seconds and drop the configuration setting here?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [sample configuration](http://elmah.googlecode.com/svn/tags/REL-1.0/samples/web.config) file from the [ELMAH Google Code site](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). Notice there are a few configuration updates you'll need to put in place. If you need a quick tutorial, Hanselman has [a decent overview](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) along with other links.I hope it helps.